# Play a DVD Video in delphi, using Windows Media Player ActiveX

Tags: delphi, windows-8, windows-media-player

I use Windows Media Player ActiveX in my Delphi application to plays videos.

When I double click on player control in design view, I've see **.IFO** and **.VOB** files are supports.

But when I choose a **VIDEO_TS.IFO** or **.VOB** file, it does not play!!!

how can I play whole dvd video?

I Found the problem is in **Windows 8**, in Windows 7 everything works OK!!

Comment: Show your code. Any error messages?

Comment: Are you aware that this cannot ever be made to work on Windows 8?

Answer (score 2):

Windows 8 chose to not to include the codecs needed for DVD playback to save money on licensing fees.

You should look into getting an external codec in order to play DVDs with windows media player activex control.

Check first if windows media player itself can play the DVD, if it can't it won't work in your application.

Answer (score 2):

[Windows 8 does not include DVD playback facilities](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/dvd-playback-help). Microsoft took this decision [to avoid paying licensing fees](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/05/04/windows_media_dvd_playback_dead/).

You'll need to find a third party component other than Windows Media Player in order to be able to support DVD playback on Windows 8. An obvious option is [VLC](https://wiki.videolan.org/Using_libvlc_with_Delphi/), but there are many possibilities.

Comment: I have been tried VLC activeX, but it can't play dvd with menu!

Comment: Then try something else. I've explained why your approach fails in Windows 8.